# How to read each line of a file as an input parameter for a Scala function?

Tags: scala, shell, hadoop, apache-spark

I previously had a shell script to do this, but it took too long to run through more than a million HDFS directories, so I'm looking at Spark options now.

Here is the scenario:
I want to extract the first line of files stored in HDFS directories. I want to be able to do this across nested directories, and not just stop with the first level directory.

First I wrote a shell script to fetch all directories (nested ones too) and put them in a text file "user_directories.txt":

```
$ hdfs dfs -ls -R /user | grep '^d' > /my-path.../user_directories.txt
```

Then I formatted the file to remove extra spaces and add ',' as delimiter:

```
tr -s ' ' ' ' < /my-path...user_directories.txt > /my-path.../user_directories_next.txt
tr ' ' ',' < /my-path.../user_directories_next.txt > /my-path../user_directories_final.txt
```

The "user_directories_final.txt" file contains fields separated by columns, and the 8th column is the directory name (full path of directory).

Next, this is what I did in Scala Spark:

```
scala> val file = sc.textFile("/my-path.../user_directories_final.txt")
```

Now to get the 8th column, I did a mapping functionality in Scala which splits with the comma as delimiter and takes the 8th field:

```
scala> val file2 = file.map(_.split(",")).map(c => c(7))
```

Here is what I try to do next:

```
scala> val firstLines=sc.hadoopFile(file2,classOf[TextInputFormat],classOf[LongWritable],classOf[Text]).flatMap {
case (k, v) => if (k.get == 0) Seq(v.toString) else Seq.empty[String]
}
```

This gives an error:

```
<console>:39: error: type mismatch;
 found   : org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[String]
 required: String
     val firstLines=sc.hadoopFile(file2,classOf[TextInputFormat],classOf[LongWritable],classOf[Text]).flatMap {
                                  ^
```

I know what is causing the error but don't know how to fix it. The above function gives the first line of file in a directory (the output that I need, except its just for one directory and I need it for all directories) if "file2" is replaced by a String path name enclosed in quotes. I have a list of path names in my "file2", so how do I make the function read each path name as a String value from the file in an iterative manner?

Comment: Can you show some lines of `user_directories_final.txt` and the script that was working to slow?

Comment: `SparkContext#hadoopFile(.)` accepts comma-separated paths as its first argument - did you try that? (assuming you collected all the paths with `file2.collect()`. This should fit on the driver's memory based on the assumption of 1 million directory names of 1kb each. However this approach fails if the directory names cannot all be collected on the driver.).

Comment: @AlexandreDupriez I am new to Spark, can you show me how to use the SparkContext#hadoopFile(.) for my particular code? My file2 contains all of the paths that I need (each line in the file is a path), and I want to read each of them in the hadoopFile function as a loop and put the output into another file.

Comment: @WalterA 

drwxr-xr-x,-,acquetl,hdfs,0,2017-04-20,18:30,/user/acquetl/hdp_acq/L2/scripts/f832135_SandBox/spark-2.0.1-bin-hadoop2.7/data/graphx
The above is a sample line from the file. The last field (path) is the one that I am interested in, and I extracted that using mapping functionality in Spark. The shell script that was too slow is:

hdfs dfs -ls -R /user/ | grep -v "^d" | awk '{print $8}' | while read file; do
    echo "${file}"
    hdfs dfs -cat ${file} | head -1
    echo
done

Comment: The `hdfs` calls are slow, not the shellscript calling them. You already made `user_directories.txt`, parsing this with `grep -v "^d" user_directories.txt | awk '{print $8}' > user_files.txt` won't take long. I am aware that this command will fail when you have files with spaces, I hope you know that to. Calling `hdfs dfs -cat ${file}` for all files in more than a million HDFS directories (hoping the `cat` will be interrupted after one line thanks to `head`) will be very slow. I think you will have the same problem with `Scala`.